# example on how to make an js confirmation popup with values from the form?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter.
if I click on submit button on a form, a popup confirmation will appear.
The quantity or any thing  that I put on the form must appear on the popup before I confirm or purchase it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with default javascript popup. I suggest you use [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default).